# How to generate Query aggregation in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am working on some code, sample table shown below. Looking for aggregated output to some query

**Sample Table**

```
col1    col2
----    ---- 
val1    Fully
val1    Partial
val2    NoService
val2    Partial
val3    Fully
val3    NoService
val3    Fully
val3    Partial
val1    Fully
val2    NoService
```

**Output expected**

```
Col1    Fully   Partial NoService   Total
----    -----   ------- ---------   ----- 
val1     2        1      0           3
val2     0        1      2           3
val3     2        1      1           4
```

Not sure how to do this in oracle? please some one help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This: It's not a dynamic solution though it will provide the result what you expect. If you have fixed values in val2 then it's the best one otherwise you have to choose dynamic way.

```
SELECT col1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'Fully' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Fully,
    SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'Partial' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Partial,
    SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'NoService' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NoService,
    COUNT(col2) total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can do this using pivot or aggregate function with `CASE`:

```
SELECT COL1, 
  COUNT(CASE when COL2 = 'FULLY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FULLY,
  COUNT(CASE when COL2 = 'PARTIAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PARTIAL
FROM TABLE_A A 
LEFT JOIN  TABLE_A B
  on B.COL1 = A.COL1
GROUP BY COL1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using pivot query function in oracle

```
select * from(select nvl(col1,'Total') col1,nvl(col2,'Total') col2,count(1) cnt from mytable group by  CUBE(col1,col2))
pivot
(
     sum(cnt)
     for col2 IN
               (
                  'Fully'  AS "Fully",
                  'Partial'   AS "Partial",
                  'NoService' AS "NoService",
                  'Total' As "Total"
               )
)
```

here from above query i can get both column and row total.

use query as per your need.